# How to reference a button in Do While within an If Else statement in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, buttonclick

I'm a newbie to VBA, and will try to make my question clear. I want to add another `If Else` statement to say when the button OR is clicked, it should to certain stuff else other. So my question is do I have to code anything within `Private Sub OR_Click() ... End Sub` first then reference it in my new `If Else` statement?

```
If .RecordCount > 0 Then
    .MoveFirst 
    Do While Not .EOF
        If Filter Is Nothing Then
            Set Filter = XFormToFilter.FilterBuilder
            Filter.SetPrimaryFilter PrimaryFilter, primaryTable, primaryKey
        End If  
        'This is where I want the button to go

        Filter.AddSubFilter "Filter" & .fields("ID"), _
            filterString, targetTable, subformDict(targetTable)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's not clear where this code is being called. Is it being called from another button?

Comment: @Zev Spitz Great point! Yes, this is called from a filter button.

Comment: The filter should be different based on whether the `OR` toggle button is checked or not -- am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Zev Spitz You're absolutely right! There are also lots of junk that I'm not showing as for what the Filter button does, my job is to add the OR function just so the filter button functions the same way as any other filters with or options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have created a toggle button in the form designer (not a standard button). Every control has a generic `Name` which Access will set unless you change it -- something like `ToggleButton115`. You can then write code within the filter handler like this:

```
If ToggleButton15 Then
    'OR option has been set; change the filter appropriately
Else
    'OR option has not been set
End If
```

NB: This works because the togglebutton's `Value` property is `True` or `False` depending on whether it has been toggled or not. The `Value` property is the **default property** -- the property VBA assumes you want to use when you don't specify a property on an object.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821471.aspx) for more details.